# Is it possible to move the caret to the first visible line of a textbox in WFA

Tags: c#

Yes it is possible with this code. Works perfectly.

This goes in your class

```
    const int EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE = 0x00CE;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32")]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

This goes in your method

```
        int ii = SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);

        textBox1.Focus();

        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;

        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(ii);
```

However in my build error list I get this warning that I am not sure how to fix

> Because it is a P/Invoke method, 'tWUtil.SendMessage(IntPtr, int, int,
>   int)' should be defined in a class named NativeMethods,
>   SafeNativeMethods, or UnsafeNativeMethods.

Comment: Rename your class.

Answer (score 0):

This is CA1060: Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class validation.

> **Cause** A method uses Platform Invocation Services to access unmanaged code and is not a member of one of the NativeMethods
>   classes.

[ca1060-move-p-invokes-to-nativemethods-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1060-move-p-invokes-to-nativemethods-class)

> **How to Fix Violations**
>
> To fix a violation of this rule, move the method to the appropriate
>   NativeMethods class. For most applications, moving P/Invokes to a new
>   class that is named NativeMethods is enough.

etc...

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the CA1060: Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class validation.

this goes in your method

```
        textBox1.Focus();
        const int EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE = 0x00CE;
        int ii = NativeMethods.SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);

        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(ii);
```

And you make this into a class

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32")]
    internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
}
```